# How to put inline quotes in an org file for html export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I am exporting an org file with org-reveal. I would like to have the following html markup when exporting:

```
<q cite="http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/Our-Favorite-Technology-Quotations">“The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from”</q>
```

What is the markup to use in org-mode for that? For `blockquote`, it would be:

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
"Everything should be made as simple as possible,
but not any simpler" -- Albert Einstein
#+END_QUOTE
```

How can I generate the `<q></q>` markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result with a macro like this (which should also work for latex, but without the url):

```org
#+MACRO: quote @@html:<q cite="$2">$1</q>@@@@latex:``$1''@@

And then there is: {{{quote(The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from,http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/Our-Favorite-Technology-Quotations)}}}.
```

Note that there is no space after the comma.

You can also simplify it a bit if you can omit the url (which is not shown anyway as far as I know):

```org
#+MACRO: quote @@html:<q>$1</q>@@@@latex:``$1''@@

And then there is: {{{quote(The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from)}}}.
```

**Edit 1:** 
Here is an example of how to define the macro globally (in your emacs configuration, e.g. in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`):

```el
(setq org-export-global-macros '((quote . "@@html:<q cite=\"$2\">$1</q>@@@@latex:``$1''@@")))
```

**Edit 2**: Simplified the macro definition.

**Edit 3**: You can also include an org file containing macros:

```org
#+INCLUDE: /path/to/org-macro-collection.org
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to define this macros in an emacs config file, and not per-org file, so that I can have a toolset of macros?

Comment: Yes, you can define them in `org-export-global-macros`, I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The [Org Mode Manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/) addresses in Section [Quoting HTML](https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-HTML-tags.html#Quoting-HTML-tags) tags directly the question `How to put raw html in an org file`.

Use `@@html:...@@` for short html snippets where the elipsis `...` stands for the html code and HTML export code blocks for longer html code blocks:

```orgmode
#+HTML: <q cite="http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/Our-Favorite-Technology-Quotations">“The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from”</q>
```

or

```orgmode
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<q cite="http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/Our-Favorite-Technology-Quotations">“The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from”</q>
#+END_EXPORT
```